# How do I compare the date of the datetimepicker form from html and another date in python

Tags: python, selenium, date, compare

This is the HTML code from the website:

```
<input class="form-control datetimepicker max-width-375" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field SelectedDate must be a date." id="SelectedDate" name="SelectedDate" type="text" value="23 Mar 2021">
```

And by using selenium and python , I am able to get the value from this element "23 Mar 2021". But how do I use/convert this value so that I can compare to another date?

The code I used to get the value from the website and print out the date and btw this is like a booking website so the dates will keep changing thus hard coding converting dates will not work:

```
Checkdate = driver.find_element_by_id("SelectedDate")
Datevalue = Checkdate.get_attribute('value')
print("Earliest Date is " + Datevalue)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use python's `datetime` to convert the string to datetime object.

```
>>import datetime
>>dt = datetime.datetime.strptime( "23 Mar 2021", '%d %b %Y')
>>dt
  datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 23, 0, 0)
```

Now you can use this `dt` variable to compare with another datetime object.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use `dateparser` library:

```
import dateparser

parsed_data = dateparser.parse("23 Mar 2021")
```